# How to prevent of removing spaces from string by Sexpr?

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Here is a string variable.

```
a <- 'This is a sample sentence'
```

If I want to print in inline text mode for PDF, I can write it this way:

```
$\Sexpr{a}$
```

But, I am getting the output like this way:

```
Thisisasamplesentence
```

How to get original string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is fully consistent with the rules of latex and R/knitr.

If you look at your expression

```
$\Sexpr{a}$
```

than you see that `knitr` substitutes `\Sexpr{a}` with `This is a sample sentence`.

The newly created `.tex` file now contains

```
$This is a sample sentence$
```

Because the sentence is enclosed by two `$` signs latex will typeset the sentence in math mode. In mathematical texts (equations) whitespaces are usually not desired. This is the reason why latex will eat up all whitespaces in math mode by default.

The following figure compares how three different variables are typeset in text and math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0.6em}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{0.6em}

\begin{document}

\section{Inline Evaluation of R Code}

<<>>=
a <- 'This is a sentence'
b <- 666
c <- '   y   =    m x +   b'
@

\bigskip 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{S{X}S{X}S{X}}
    \toprule
                        & \texttt{\textbackslash Sexpr\{<Variable>\}} & \texttt{\textbf{\$}\textbackslash Sexpr\{<Variable>\}\textbf{\$}}  \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Variable \texttt{a} & \Sexpr{a}                                   & $\Sexpr{a}$ \tabularnewline
    Variable \texttt{b} & \Sexpr{b}                                   & $\Sexpr{b}$ \tabularnewline
    Variable \texttt{c} & \Sexpr{c}                                   & $\Sexpr{c}$ \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!